# Covering $\mathbb{R}^n$ by countably many lower dimensional pieces?

Tags: differential-geometry

I would like to know if it is possible to cover $\mathbb{R}^n$ by countably many immersed submanifold of dimension less than $n$. A similar version is whether it is possible to cover $\mathbb{C}^n$ by countably many analytic subsets of lower dimension.

The motivation is that an exercise I am working involves in proving a statement being true for a generic lattice, which seems to invoke statements of the sort above, but I am not sure how I can prove them. Thanks!

Comment: Idea: (1) embedded submanifolds of lower dimension are nowhere dense; (2) an immersed submanifold is a countable union of embedded submanifolds; (3) the Baire category theorem.

Comment: Ah, Baire's theorem of course! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Nate:  Why not post this as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the idea of a proof:

1. Embedded submanifolds of lower dimension are nowhere dense.
2. An immersed submanifold is a countable union of embedded submanifolds.
3. The Baire category theorem.

Another, similar approach would be to argue that that embedded submanifolds of lower dimension have Lebesgue measure zero.